# Choose Typescript type/interface conditionally on external condition

Tags: typescript

I would like to choose a TS interface or type based on an external condition other that what is being typed.

The external condition could be a feature toggle for example.

I will try to explain my point:

```
type NotNullableName = string;
type NullableName = string | null;

const getNotNullableName = (name: NotNullableName) => name
const getNullableName = (name: NullableName) => name
```

At the moment I have to do:

```
const getName =  externalCondition ? getNotNullableName :  getNullableName;
```

But I would like to achieve something like this:

```
const getName = (name: externalCondition ? NotNullableName : NullableName) => name
```

Is there anyway I could achieve that?

[I am providing a TS playground to make my point clear](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sGBXANighgIxRG6C20AvFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3AFCiSyoba4HFmW10oAHyg0OzJgGM4NclDoRECZGiw48hKCQAUNHgC5Yyjmu6EAlFoB8onlJlyFiE1w29dB9qtc9LRG3qETCzg0ADCABZwcKQQNFpQlEjQAPxGzt7qPFCGKpxZQfaywPKKbgkehIboNCAACugUBGnwGflm0LkuBRB%20AXbSxaWIPAAqAO5wFYEQhpHRsTR9tkFAA)

Comment: I am not sure what are you looking for. Maybe smth like [this](https://catchts.com/type-negation) ?

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarianfromUkraine but that is too complicated for what I am looking for and not very flexible.

I the end I think I will just do:
```const getName = (name: NotNullableName | NullableName) => name

const nameNull = getName(null);
const nameNotNull = getName('anyName');
```

So I will use union to broad the interface options.

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not find a better way I opted for using an union to allow both interfaces:

```
const getName = (name: NotNullableName | NullableName) => name

const nameNull = getName(null);
const nameNotNull = getName('anyName');
```

[I completed the TS sample just in case it helps somebody else.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sGBXANighgIxRG6C20AvFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3AFCiSyoba4HFmW10oAHyg0OzJgGM4NclDoRECZGiw48hKCQAUNHgC5Yyjmu6EAlFoB8onlJlyFiE1w29dB9qtc9LRG3qETCzg0ADCABZwcKQQNFpQlEjQAPxGzt7qPFCGKpxZQfaywPKKbgkehLnGmWbQInmmbn4BdkVygbgcCU5uuhzmzNLFtoTwGSg9ZTzaAOToNCBus4NAA)

Thanks!